# Find $\lim x_n$ if $ \sum_{k=1}^n kx_k = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^k $

Tags: limits

I was playing with some ideas for sequences of real numbers and I came up with this problem.

Let $x_n$ be a sequence of positive non-zero numbers such that:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^n kx_k = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^k $$ for all integers $n$.
Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n$.

My solution:

Let $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^n kx_k = \prod_{k=1}^n x_k^k$ which is greater than $0$ because all the term of the sum are pozitive.

$$ S_{n+1} = S_n + (n+1)x_{n+1} = S_n x_{n+1}^{n+1}  $$ for all integers $n$
which leads to
$$ \frac{S_n}{n+1} = \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}^{n+1}-1} $$ which is  pozitive meaning that $x_n \geq 1$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \geq 1$.

Using Cesaro-Stolz $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{S_n}{n+1} = \lim_{n \to \infty} S_{n+1}-S_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1)x_{n+1}.$ 
Substituting we get :

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1)x_{n+1}= \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x_{n+1}}{x_{n+1}^{n+1}-1} $$
because $\lim_{n \to \infty} x_n \neq 0$ 
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} (n+1) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{x_{n+1}^{n+1}-1} = \infty  \iff $$

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  x_{n+1}^{n+1} = 1. $$

$x_n^n \geq x_n \geq 1$ because $x_n \geq 1$ so

$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  x_n^n \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}  x_n^n \geq 1 \iff 
1 \geq \lim_{n \to \infty}  x_n \geq 1 \iff $
$$ \lim_{n \to \infty}  x_n = 1$$

Is this solution right?

Comment: Please rewrite your title to be *informative* (actually refer to the *content* of the question) so others can find the problem and its answers later.

Comment: Did you intend that the sum on the left converge?  You might have a problem if the terms don't go to zero...

Comment: @EricTowers what's the problem? I dont see it

Comment: If $x_k \rightarrow 1$, then $k x_k \not \rightarrow 0$.  What is the simplest (non-)convergence test?

Comment: @EricTowers I get that now, but, if the sum is divergent I think there are  sequences with that propriety because we can generate one choosing an $x_1$ and using the formula for $\frac{S_n}{n+1}$

Answer (score 2):

If the limit exists
and is $L$,
then

$\sum_{k=1}^n kL \approx \prod_{k=1}^n L^k
$
or
$Ln(n+1)/2 \approx L^{n(n+1)/2}
$
or
$L 
\approx (n(n+1)/2)^{1/((n(n+1)/2-1)}
$
and since
$n^{1/n} \to 1$,
$L = 1$.

Comment: Well that was easier than what I did :)

Comment: Of course, it assumes that the limit exists. That is the hard part.